# Locating a data file when writing a mex function for MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I have troubles writing a mex file in which I load external data stored in a data file. The problem is related to locating/finding the correct path of the data file, in relation to the current working path in MATLAB. For example, assume I have a folder `myfolder` where I put 1) the mex executable `prog.mex` and 2) the data file `data.txt`. Now in my mex source I can try to locate the data file by writing

```
if(access("data.txt", F_OK) == 1) { // load the file etc. }
```

This works fine, as long as I execute the mex file AFTER browsing in MATLAB to the folder `myfolder`. However, I want to be able to call the mex file from everywhere, i.e. by adding the path to `myfolder` via MATLAB's `addpath()` function. Then, obviously, even though I can still execute the mex file, the data file cannot be located any more. Is it still possible somehow to be able to locate the data file somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you pass the data file name and location as an argument to the MEX function ?

Comment: Alternatively, you could probably combine `mexFunctionName` and `which` (via `mexCallMatlab` or `mexEvalString`) to get the directory in which your mex-file resides. Then assemble the full path to the datafile, instead of a relative one.